# Adding a UILabel to a view from outside the ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView in a ViewController which creates and displays a label.  And, it does it just fine.  What I'd like to do, though, is to be able to call methods in other class files, and have them be able to add UILabels to my view as well, but I'm having trouble doing that.

I've tried some of the other answers here on SO, such as this:

[How to perform a [self.view addSubview: lbl] outside of ViewController Class scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796979/how-to-perform-a-self-view-addsubview-lbl-outside-of-viewcontroller-class-sco)

But that didn't work in my project, for some reason. I must not be not applying it right, or maybe someone else has another take?

I've tried maybe a dozen different approaches.  It seems like one way this could work would be that I would create my UIView in my ViewController as a property so that it's accessible from other classes, then, in my other class file, I could create a new instance that's a member of that ViewController class, and then add new subviews to that, and they would show up. But, I'm wrong. Here's my latest wrongness.

```
--ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OtherClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property UIView *myView;

@end

--ViewContoller.m 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];

    self.myView = (UIView *)self.view;

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    myLabel.text = @"Label #1";

    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,200,50);

    [self.myView addSubview:myLabel];

    OtherClass *oc = [[OtherClass alloc] init];


    [oc methodInOtherClass];

}

--OtherClass.m

- (void) methodInOtherClass {

    NSLog(@"hello!  In the other class file now.");

    UILabel *nooLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    nooLabel.text = @"Label #2!”;

    nooLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 75, 100, 50);

    nooLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *nooView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    nooView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [nooView addSubview:nooLabel];

    ViewController *myView2 = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    [myView2.myView addSubview:nooView];

}

@end
```

Comment: `-methodInOtherClass` creates a new view controller instead of using the existing one.

Comment: "then, in my other class file, I could create a new instance that's a member of that ViewController class, and then add new subviews to that, and they would show up." -- That's your major misconception.

Comment: Drat. There was at least one, maybe 2 other answers up here that were interesting & had some thoughtful discussion that people were kind enough to contribute, and I was pursuing one especially about using delegates.  But I refreshed the page to see if anyone had anything to add and now specifically that answer and its discussion seem to be gone. Any way to get those back? I'm sorry, I've never posted here before. I've been lurking for like a year but have never posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your view into the other class's method.  Right now, you are creating a view controller and adding a label to it, but you aren't doing anything with the new view controller.

In the first class:

```
[oc methodInOtherClass:self.view];
```

in the second class:

```
- (void) methodInOtherClass:(UIView*)view {

    UILabel *nooLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nooLabel.text = @"Label #2!”;
    nooLabel.frame = CGRectMake(75, 75, 100, 50);
    nooLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIView *nooView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    nooView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [nooView addSubview:nooLabel];

    [view addSubview:nooView];
}
```

As other's have pointed out, this is likely not the right way to go about this in the first place, but I'll make no assumptions about your architecture here.